# Does Exact Audio Copy support any scripting in filename construction?

Tags: filenames, ripping, exact-audio-copy

In some media players including (MPC, foobar2000) it is possible to format the output of a playlist by using if control structures to select certain meta tags based on their presence, or others if they are not in the media file.

E.g

```
[[[[%albumartist]|[%artist%]]&[ - %album%]&[ [-%track%]- %title% [(%time%)]]]|%file%]
```

This `--format` parameter would make MPC display the artist, album and title if they were all present, or fallback on the file name otherwise. Foobar2000 uses different syntax, but to the same effect.

I'm wondering if this can be done in EAC for the output file names.

Perhaps if nothing like this is built-in (I checked Hydrogen and the German wiki), there is a lame.exe wrapper that can be used instead to get the effect I'm looking for.

---

I could probably pull off writing a C++ wrapper of my own, but the EAC SDK is commercial with zilch official documentation. I have to admit I'm feeling kinda cheap here, but as the author states "the licensing cost is most probably only affordable for commercial projects". Maybe I'm over thinking this and all parameters are simply passed to the encoder in a standard way?

Answer (score 0):

EAC supports the use of various *placeholders* for file naming:

[image: 1]

A complete list can be found [here](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=EAC_placeholders). Also see the **Which flags can I use for the filename creation scheme?** and **Which flags can I use in the external compression scheme “User Defined MP3 Encoder”?** sections of the [FAQ](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/en/index.php/support/faq/).

Comment: that's pretty close to the 'standard' system I see. I generally just check the tags, and use the tag->filename option in my standalone tag editor to do this tho

Comment: Perhaps my question is not clear enough. I want to "branch" a file name/path to be A if %placeholder% exists and B if %placeholder% does not exist. A particular use case may involve creating sub folders for albums that have more than one cd. Another may involve creating a different folder name for albums with various artists, but that particular scenario is covered.

Comment: Generally you [specify an external encoder](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3c5tx.png) such as Flac.exe and pass it command-line options which include the tags. I don't think what you want can be done with EAC itself, but perhaps you can specify your own batch file/script as the external app to be invoked, which in turn could have whatever naming/saving logic you want.